# AWS Application controlled Stickiness cookies in .NET

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, httpcookie, cookie-httponly

Does anyone have .NET implementation using AWS application controlled stickiness cookies? I have LB generated stickiness cookies [usually it's named as "AWSELB"] which does not support HttpOnly Secure flag. For security reasons, I need to change this to application controlled stickiness. For this, what are the code level changes (in .NET side) to be done so that I could set the HttpOnly Secure Flag?

More Info on AWS Stickiness session cookies:

AWS has two session stickiness cookies in general.

1. Duration-Based Session Stickiness
2. Application-Controlled Session Stickiness

Duration based session stickiness can be generated by AWS and this cannot have HttpOnly Secure flag. Application controlled stickiness is handled from application side and this has option to set httponly Secure flag.

I am looking for .NET examples.

Comment: I'm facing something similar. Have you found a solution to this? I haven't tried it yet, but wouldn't we be able to retrieve the cookie by name, "AWSALB" and then set the attribute values that way? 
[Cookie.Secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx)